# How to filter options in app maker's SuggestBox

Tags: google-app-maker

I need to implement filtering for options in SuggestBox.
I've tried to do it differently, but none of my attempts worked out:

1. Using Model instead of Options/Value; Create calculated SQL model and pass the parameter for filtration:

Didn't work: suggestBox doesn't have event or anything to call before it loads data, so if you pass param for query before typing anything in -- it is not seen an you get an error:

```
Please provide value for the parameter ":Param" used in the query Error: Please provide value for the parameter ":Param" used in the query
Query for record suggest oracle: (Error) : Please provide value for the parameter ":Param" used in the query
Query for record suggest oracle failed.
```

2. Using Options/Value

It seems that it is impossible to have different properties of an object when passing it to Suggest Box. For example, I want user to see an user-friendly field *Name* and work with a record or at least record's Id, but if you specify *Name* as an option and *Id* as a value, Name is being written to a SuggestBox and now we get a validation error because *Name* is a string and *Id* is a Number.

Please help me realize where I'm wrong or show me a workaround for this.
Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problems. Suggestbox, seems to restrict too much, I tried using a calculated sql model with an inbound param, that did not work.

Comment: Go with a dropdown with the filter in first step. Disable dropdown till filter value selected.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as well. I gave up on the suggest box and created a pop up form. With a query builder model for the data source. The only thing i don't like is that it seems to be case sensitive.

something like:

```
YourFilterColumn startsWith? :Param
```

Add a table view and then you can add a text box and set the oninputchange event to:

```
widget.datasource.query.parameters.Param = widget.value;
widget.datasource.load();
```

Then you can start typing select the record you want and pass it back to your form with a button.

like this if it is a relational field:

```
app.pages.YourPage.children.YourForm.datasource.item.YourItem = 
widget.datasource.item;
```

or something like this if you just need a value (haven't tested this):

```
app.pages.YourPage.children.YourForm.datasource.item.YourItem = 
widget.datasource.item.YourValue;
```

Probably add a couple lines to clear the form out:

```
widget.root.descendants.TextBox1.value = "";
widget.datasource.query.parameters.Param = "";
widget.datasource.load();
```